# Adding custom label and value to jQueryUI Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to populate custom values using jQueryUI slider from the values stored in an array. Whenever I try to change the min and max value along with step methods, it doesn't show the result as expected. Any help towards the right approach would be appreciated?

[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/Zxq77WEgmwIoHoN0CJt0)

```
  $(function() {
    var steps = [{"10": "$15"}, {"25": "$20"}, {"50": "$35"}, {"100": "$60"}, {"250": "$125"}, {"500": "$200"}, {"1000": "$300"}];

   $( "#slider" ).slider({
      value:100,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 100,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
          $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Where does `steps` come into this? I can't see it being used anywhere.

Comment: that is the question I have asked? how to utilize steps array with jQueryUI slider?

Comment: You can't unfortunately. Your best bet would be to use the `change` event and update the `step` value.

Comment: So you can get the handle value during `slide` or `stop`. You can then use that in your array... but... this is a very strange way to work with the data. When the `value` is 10, do you want to get the 10th index of the array or do you want to the object that has "10" as a index?

Comment: from the array the key will be label and the value will be that value and slide will be specific to these values only

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I *think* you're trying to do, could make the following changes:

**HTML**

```
<p>
  <label for="amount">Donation amount ($50 increments):</label>
  <input type="text" readonly id="amount" value="$100" />
</p>

<div id="slider"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  var steps = {
    10: "$15",
    25: "$20",
    50: "$35",
    100: "$60",
    250: "$125",
    500: "$200",
    1000: "$300"
  };
  $("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 500,
    range: 'min',
    step: 10,
    animate: 0,
    value: 100,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(steps[ui.value]);
    }
  });
});
```

But I think what you may really want to do it this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uL3j7q05/6/

**JQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1000,
    range: 'min',
    step: 50,
    animate: 0,
    value: 100,
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      $("#amount").val("$" + ui.value);
    }
  });
});
```